# MULTIPLE STEP OLEDB OPERATION GENERATED ERRORS

Tags: vb6, oledb

when i tried to connect to sql database it is giving me the following error
MULTIPLE STEP OLEDB OPERATION GENERATED ERRORS
MY CODE IS

```
Public Sub connect(sql As String)
    Security Info=False"
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & " \HMS.sdf;"
    If rs.State Then rs.Close
    rs.Open sql, con, adOpenKeyset
End Sub
```

Comment: This code looks wrong - can you correct the line that currently says `Security Info=False"`?

Comment: You need to show us what the value of `sql` is when you get this error.

Comment: If you step through the code in debug on exactly which line is your error thrown?

Comment: This error usually means that you are trying to store too much information.  Specifically, if you have a string column defined at a certain length and you try to put a string that is too long in to it.